# How to create a game board on Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, visualization

I want to recreate Game Fifteen in Python, but I'm stuck on drawing a board in two dimensions. I did this before in C and I tried using lists again like the following:

```
numbers = d * d - 1
global blankx, blanky, board
blankx = d - 1
blanky = d - 1

for i in range(d):
    for j in range(d):
        board[i][j] = numbers
        numbers -= 1
board[blankx][blanky] = d * d
```

Where d is the dimension, blankx and y are the coordinates for the blank space in the bottom right corner. It says however:
'list index out of range' on line board[i][j] = numbers
I don't get why though, any tips?

Comment: How did you initialize the global variables? (And why are they global?)

Comment: @kazemakase I used those variables in other functions, too, so that's why they are global. They are: board = [], blankx = 0, blanky = 0

Comment: `board = []` means you have an empty board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, accessing an index of a `list` does not automatically extend the `list` to the minimum requisite length. You will have to either initialize an empty board, or create and populate it together. I'd recommend a `list` comprehension:

```
board = [[d*d-1-i-d*j for i in range(d)] for j in range(d)]
```

This is equivalent to the following explicit loop, which adds new items to each `list` with `append()`:

```
board = []
for i in range(d):
    row = []
    for j in range(d):
        row.append(d*d-1-i-d*j)
    board.append(row)
```

Comment: Your board numbers are all the same. See my variant.

Comment: That should be better.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TigerhawkT3

Comment: @DóraJámbor - Sounds like it worked for you. You can indicate that this answer solved the issue by clicking the "accept" button below its score.

Comment: upvoted and thanks for the comments. I thought the numbers had to be grouped by column.

Comment: @Pynchia - As you might have noticed, I had a bit of difficulty as well. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
board = [[i*d + j + 1 for i in range(d)] for j in range(d)]
board[blankx][blanky] = d * d
```

Comment: Maybe an explanation of what was wrong and how to fix it would be good?